# Dart Server for Flutter on Web in Docker

Tags: docker, flutter, dart, server, flutter-web

I'm trying to build a dart server that can serve flutter web apps. I've tried it a few different ways, building [from scratch](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-dart-server-from-scratch-2ee0cf88948), using [shelf](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf) (and [shelf_static](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf_static)), and lastly GetX, but I can't get them to run in a docker container. For instance, I currently have a simple structure:

```
-myApp/
  -web/
  -Dockerfile
  -pubspec.yaml
  -server.dart
```

I took the basic flutter demo app (with the floating button & counter), added web support, then did `$ flutter build web`, and took the build/web folder and copied it here as just web. Pubspec only includes get_server and build_runner, the server.dart file is only:

```
import 'package:get_server/get_server.dart';
void main() => runApp(GetServer(home: FolderWidget('web')));
```

And then my Dockerfile looks like this (based on [this github repo](https://github.com/subfuzion/dart-docker-slim)):

```
################
FROM google/dart:2.10

RUN apt -y update && apt -y upgrade

WORKDIR /app
COPY pubspec.yaml /app/pubspec.yaml
RUN dart pub get
COPY . .
RUN dart pub get --offline

RUN dart pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
RUN dart compile exe /app/server.dart -o /app/server

########################
FROM subfuzion/dart:slim
COPY --from=0 /app /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/server"]
```

If I run the server from the command line:

```
$ dart server.dart
```

It runs perfectly. But if I build docker and run it:

```
$ docker build -t myApp .
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 myapp
```

It just says that the page can't be found. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Or have suggestions for how to host a Flutter Web App using a Dart Server (it doesn't have to be GetX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to update this because this is my only post that gets any traffic. The first answer was that I'm an idiot trying to serve the website from the same directory on my computer as in my docker container (suprise! that didn't work). Secondly, I've created some automation scripts that speeds this process and allows it to be easily [pushed to Google's CloudRun](https://github.com/MayJuun/servers) in case anyone is interested. I'm also going to change to showing a Shelf server, since this seems to be the default now.

My full directory setup for my Flutter project is just this:

```
directory_to_flutter_project/
simple_server/
scripts/
```

Inside `simple_server` I have a dart project with 2 folders, `bin` and `web`. `bin` contains only `server.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:functions_framework/serve.dart';
import 'package:shelf_static/shelf_static.dart';

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  await serve(args, _nameToFunctionTarget);
}

FunctionTarget? _nameToFunctionTarget(String name) {
  switch (name) {
    case 'function':
      return FunctionTarget.http(
        createStaticHandler('app/web', defaultDocument: 'index.html'),
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

The `web` directory is where we're going to build our Flutter PWA. You may want to include a [redirect.html](https://github.com/MayJuun/servers/blob/main/simple_shelf_server/web/redirect.html) file in it if you need any kind of authorization.

Then, when you're ready, you can create a bash script like so (I put this in the `scripts` directory):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

projectId="gcp-project-id"
projectName="gcp-project-name"
version="3"

# only needed the first time
gcloud config set project $projectId
gcloud auth login

# change to primary app directory & build flutter web & go back to main level

cd directory_to_flutter_project && flutter build web && cd ..

# if you're having issues with rendering, which we were, you can try the following instead
cd directory_to_flutter_project && flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release && cd ..

# clear web directory from server
rm simple_server/web -r

# copy the built web folder to the server directory
cp directory_to_flutter_project/build/web simple_server/web -r

# change to the server directory
cd simple_server &&

# Create docker container
docker build -t $projectName .

#
# The rest is for pushing to GCP
#

#push it to GCP Cloud Repository
docker build -t gcr.io/$projectId/$projectName:v$version .
docker push gcr.io/$projectId/$projectName:v$version

# return back to root directory
cd ..

# deploy on google cloud
gcloud run deploy $projectName --image gcr.io/$projectId/$projectName:v$version
```